# c++ compile fail with error: no member named 'snprintf' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, xcode, stl

It can be compiled successfully a few minutes ago.
And the issue cames after my trying to build the project by pressing the "Profile" button. After that, my project cannot be compiled any more.

The error message is:

```
In file included from /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/latte_prefix.h:24:
In file included from /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream:44:
In file included from /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:44:
In file included from /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:42:
In file included from /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:44:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/c++locale.h:48:
In file included from /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cstdio:52:
In file included from /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdio.h:37:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/cstdio:46:14: error: no member named 'snprintf' in namespace 'std'
  using std::snprintf;
        ~~~~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/cstdio:47:14: error: no member named 'vsnprintf' in namespace 'std'
  using std::vsnprintf;
        ~~~~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/cstdio:49:14: error: no member named 'vfscanf' in namespace 'std'
  using std::vfscanf;
        ~~~~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/cstdio:50:14: error: no member named 'vscanf' in namespace 'std'
  using std::vscanf;
        ~~~~~^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/cstdio:51:14: error: no member named 'vsscanf' in namespace 'std'
  using std::vsscanf;
        ~~~~~^
In file included from /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/latte_prefix.h:24:
In file included from /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iostream:44:
In file included from /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ostream:44:
In file included from /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/ios:42:
In file included from /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd:44:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/c++locale.h:48:
/Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cstdio:99:11: error: no member named 'FILE' in the global namespace
  using ::FILE;
        ~~^
/Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cstdio:100:11: error: no member named 'fpos_t' in the global namespace
  using ::fpos_t;
        ~~^
/Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../../../../../../../../usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cstdio:102:11: error: no member named 'clearerr' in the global namespace
  using ::clearerr;
        ~~^
```

the compile script is:

```
ProcessPCH++ /var/folders/r7/g6yvk_7s2zg0w0tndvr74qwc0000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/latte_prefix-calwfgjtbaftrwfxqlbgygvcoqtm/latte_prefix.h.pth latte_prefix.h normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++-header -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wc++11-extensions -DNET_DUMP=0 -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -fasm-blocks -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -g -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/build/latte.build/Debug/latte.build/latte.hmap -I/Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte -I/Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/../../sdk -I/Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/build/Debug/include -I/Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/build/latte.build/Debug/latte.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/build/latte.build/Debug/latte.build/DerivedSources -Wall -F/Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/build/Debug --serialize-diagnostics /var/folders/r7/g6yvk_7s2zg0w0tndvr74qwc0000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/latte_prefix-calwfgjtbaftrwfxqlbgygvcoqtm/latte_prefix.h.dia -c /Users/wangyj1203/workspace/project_x/svn/src/c++/src/latte/latte_prefix.h -o /var/folders/r7/g6yvk_7s2zg0w0tndvr74qwc0000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/latte_prefix-calwfgjtbaftrwfxqlbgygvcoqtm/latte_prefix.h.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /var/folders/r7/g6yvk_7s2zg0w0tndvr74qwc0000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/latte_prefix-calwfgjtbaftrwfxqlbgygvcoqtm/latte_prefix.h.d
```

Comment: Why both `cstdio` and `stdio.h` are being included in the build process ? Strange.

Comment: Also, check [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3091852?start=0&tstart=0) at Apple discussions forum.

Comment: It's very strange. I just click Profile button, and can't compile any more. I haven't modified any codes or project files.

Comment: If I use Makefile in terminal it will build successful. but can't build in Xcode (version 4.3.2)

Answer (score 4):

`snprintf()` comes from the `C99` standard. You should not use namespace `std` for it. Just use the global namespace.

Don't forget to include `stdio.h`

Comment: C++11 encapsulates this. So XCode's libc++ has it as well.

Comment: But C++11 is not yet that spread at the moment. I would recommend using oldschool timeproven syntax.

Comment: Didn't you mean `cstdio` instead of `stdio.h`?

Comment: @SergeyK. I tried it out, works either way. I just thought that <stdio.h> is deprecated in C++